# Date conversion

Tags: scala, date

I have a date variable

```
var date: Date = new Date()
```

then I have converted this date to String:

```
var dateStr = date.toString()
```

now I need to convert back this String to date.
I have tried both:

1:

```
   var stringToDate: Date = date2Str.asInstanceOf[Date]
```

and 2:

```
stringToDate: Date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(dateStr);
```

But in both case I got the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

Comment: I need to converta a date of the following format :
"22-AUG-11" to date !!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I see a couple of problems in your code, but this works fine:

```
scala> val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
format: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@9586200

scala> format.format(new java.util.Date())
res4: java.lang.String = 21-03-2011

scala> format.parse("21-03-2011")
res5: java.util.Date = Mon Mar 21 00:00:00 CET 2011
```

Comment: This is super . 
How can I converta a date of the following format : "22-AUG-11" to date

Comment: @Echo "dd-MMM-yy"... see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Please note that DateFormat **is not thread safe**. It can save you a day of debugging. Take a look at the joda wrapper in the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.11`, targeting `Java 8`, the `java.time` Date Time API can be used:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")

LocalDate.now().format(dtf)        // "06-07-2018"
LocalDate.parse("06-07-2018", dtf) // java.time.LocalDate = 2018-07-06
```

Note that:

- This is part of the standard library (no need for third party dependencies)
- This is [meant to replace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) the old `java.util.Date`/`SimpleDateFormat` api.
- This is also [supposed to replace](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) the widely used `joda-time` library:

  > Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.
- And by association [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) which is a wrapper around `joda-time`.

Answer (score 3):

Your first try should give you a ClassCastException because you cannot cast.aString to a Date.   the second try does not seem to be using the right format that [`Date.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) prints.  The toString method of java.utility.Date returns a String in the format specified in the javadoc.

Comment: About the second approach , I need to convert the following string "22-AUG-11" to a date .
How !!

Comment: How about the format String `dd-MMM-yy`.  Check the [javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which gives a run down on what you can use in the date pattern.

Answer (score 3):

using [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) the following worked for me :

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

val ysterday= (DateTime.now- 1.days).toString(StaticDateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd"))
```