# How to convert String to date time in Scala?

Tags: scala, datetime

I am new to Scala and I've learned it for the last few days. I have a doubt about Scala's date converting from string.

How to convert String to Date and time using Scala ?

Does it work the same way as Java?

When I do it that way, I get a compiler error and I can't convert that into Scala because I am new to Scala. And I know that it's not good to convert Java to Scala...

Please share your answer.

Comment: Yep.. it works in the same way as in Java.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5377949/920271

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you are using Java's util.Date then like in java:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
format.parse("2013-07-06")
```

docs for formating - [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

or if you are using joda's DateTime, then call parse method:

```
DateTime.parse("07-06-2013")
```

docs - [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)

Comment: Is there any package in scala library containing implicits of this conversion? Something like Duration.

Comment: @Jatin no, but you can write it by yourself: `implicit def str2date(str: String) = DateTime.parse(str)`

Comment: If you plan to have more than one execution thread on your application, you shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat`, nor `java.util.Date`, since they are not thread-safe (caveat is valid for Java 7-). In this case, consider `joda.time`.

Answer (score 6):

My go-to option is to use nscala-time: https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time

Add this to your build.sbt if using sbt.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0"
```

Import and parse your date.

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

DateTime.parse("2014-07-06")
```

Answer (score 5):

For Scala 2.11.8 (Java 1.8.0_162)

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val datetime_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
val date_int_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val last_extract_value="2018-05-09 10:04:25.375"
last_extract_value: String = 2018-05-09 10:04:25.375
//String to Date objects 
val string_to_date = datetime_format.parse(last_extract_value)
java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor = {},ISO resolved to 2018-05-08T21:01:15.402
//Date Back to string 
date_int_format.format(string_to_date)
res18: String = 20180508
```