# Scala: filter a string date by an hour range?

Tags: scala

I am using Scala and trying to filter a dataset on a string column with a date and time value. I have been looking at several posts and trying to use `SimpleDateFormat` techniques to no avail.

My sample data is:

```
+----------------------+
|my_date_str           |
+----------------------+
|12/11/2018 08:01:55 AM|
|12/11/2018 08:33:22 PM|
|12/13/2018 09:25:28 PM|
|12/17/2018 07:27:36 PM|
+----------------------+
```

I'd like to keep rows between 7pm and 9pm (date does not matter, only time). I would expect to keep these two rows of the four:

```
12/17/2018 07:27:36 PM
12/11/2018 08:33:22 PM
```

I can hack this together using `substring` functions but I imagine there is a better way using a `to_date` or a `unix` function (I tried converting to seconds with `unix_timestamp()` then extrapolating the time somehow?), isolating the time, and checking the hour value.

```
// Filter down to rows between 7 and 9 and PM
my_data.withColumn("hour_str", substring($"my_date_str", 12, 8))
    .filter( (substring($"my_date_str", -2, 2) === "PM") && ($"my_date_str" >= "07:00:00") && ($"my_date_str" <= "09:00:00") )
    .show(truncate=false)
```

Too many failed attempts to include but these are a couple posts I used:
[How to convert unix timestamp to date in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134969/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-in-spark)
[How to convert String to date time in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996549/how-to-convert-string-to-date-time-in-scala)

If it's not clear, question is how to effectively filter a string date by an hour range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "normal" timestamp, not unix_timestamp.

Something like this should work, though I am somewhat rusty on the exact incantantions:

```
df
.withColumn(
  "hour", 
  hour(to_timestamp($"foo", "MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss a"))
).filter($"hour" between (19,20))
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to get the pattern correct as well. In the conversion, an AM row returns the correct hour but the PM rows are null.

Comment: This seems to work correctly: hour(to_timestamp($"foo", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))